# How can I set up poclbm (a bitcoin miner)?

Tags: 12.10, bitcoin

I'm trying to set up poclbm on my 12.10 machine. My graphics card (as stated in system settings) is an '`Intel® 965GM x86/MMX/SSE2`'. I am trying to use the guide [here](https://bitcointalk.org/?topic=2636) but python-pyopencl can't be installed -

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 python-pyopencl : Depends: opencl-icd but it is not installable
                   Depends: python-pyopencl-headers (= 2012.1-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: python-pyopencl-doc but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: python-opengl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Has anyone got any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance, Microbug

Comment: there is a bit-coin site on stack-exchange that might be able to help too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tibor in his article creates a dummy deb that allows python-pyopencl to be installed fine.

http://tuxicate.blogspot.co.uk/2013_04_01_archive.html

This worked for me, I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to this guys question [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470670/opencl-on-mobile-intelr-965-express-chipset-family) basically poclbm requires opencl. This is the technology that allows your graphics card to be used as processor (in layman's terms). The guide you linked to is for Nvidia cards. ATI also has a good driver for opencl. But your graphics card is Intel and there is no Intel opencl driver available for Ubuntu.

The [poclbm page](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Poclbm) says which graphic cards work in the first sentence: Works with AMD - 4xxx and up, Nvidia - 8xxx and up, video cards.